# JPA Unknow column in table aliases with Pagination/Page in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, repository

In spring implementing pagination with a custom query I request:

```
{{host}}:8080/list?page=0&size=2 and the result is OK
{{host}}:8080/list?page=0&size=3 and the result is OK
{{host}}:8080/list?page=0&size=4 and the result is OK
{{host}}:8080/list?page=0&size=1 and the result is NOT OK
{{host}}:8080/list?page=1&size=1 and the result is NOT OK
{{host}}:8080/list?page=1&size=2 and the result is NOT OK
{{host}}:8080/list?page=1&size=3 and the result is NOT OK
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/list")
public Page<User> list(Pageable pageable) {
    try {
        return userRepository.findUser(pageable);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Ex: {}", e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Query(value = "select U.*, M.local as LocalM from user U inner join Morada M on M.idmorada = U.morada", nativeQuery= true)
public Page<User> findUser(Pageable pageable);
```

What happens when the response is not ok:

```
2020-01-03 11:34:01.659  WARN 9652 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1054, SQLState: 42S22
2020-01-03 11:34:01.659 ERROR 9652 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unknown column 'U' in 'field list'
```

Why does the pagination properties size and page only work in certain scenarios with the nativeQuery?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Spring repositories (yet) but you're returning a page of `User` entities while your query is selecting all user columns as well as `M.local` - I'd assume that the framework would stumble over that in any case.

Comment: But imagine the user is a projection and I need almost all the fields of U (user) and an alias from one column of M (Morada). What would the best approach be to reach a solution in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need a count query for the pagination to work, like below -

```
@Query(
  value = "select U.*, M.local as LocalM from user U inner join Morada M on M.idmorada = U.morada", 
  countQuery = "select count(*) from user U inner join Morada M on M.idmorada = U.morada", 
  nativeQuery = true)
Page<User> findUser(Pageable pageable);
```

For Spring JPA ver prior to 2.4, you need a workaround in sql stmt like -

```
value = "select U.*, M.local as LocalM from user U inner join Morada M on M.idmorada = U.morada order by U.id \n-- #pageable\n"
```

The #pageable placeholder tells Spring Data JPA how to parse the query and inject the pageable parameter.
As far as projection is concerned you could use a interface to map your resultset like -

```
public interface IUser {
public getId();
... getter methods from User entity
public getLocalM();
}
```

Comment: adding countQuery solved the problem for me, but I have a long query it's a little bit awkward to have it also in countQuery! is there any update to do it without this solution please